# C# how to write JSON with enumerated identifiers

Tags: c#, json, excel, linq, replace

I am writing a code to convert Excel to JSON (so far it works).
But I got a problem, I need to number each line that I am writing after the word Match_ (Aka Match_1, Match_2, Match_3).
If you look towards the end of the code, I tried to maybe put For? but than it gives me all Match_i..
How can I use `Replace` command so I can actually put corresponding numbers after the word Match_?

IP = another string I am adding to the sentence. Ignore it

row[0] = the text its taking as is from the row from the excel

Match_ is not a var, its literally a text taken, I can also write there Oded_  and then it will write Oded_ = (IP string) + (excel text on row[0])

Match_ is a text I am actually trying to replace from within the text, as I cannot do FOR inside the Link Query.

```cs
using (var conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
{
    conn.Open();

    var cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = $"SELECT * FROM [{sheetName}$]";

    using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if (rdr != null)
        {
            //LINQ query - when executed will create anonymous objects for each row
            var query = rdr.Cast<DbDataRecord>().Select(row => new
            {
                Match_ = IP + row[0]
            });


            //Generates JSON from the LINQ query
         
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(query);


        //Write the file to the destination path

        for (int i = 1; i<200; i++)
        {
            json = json.Replace("match_", "match_" + i );
        }
        File.WriteAllText(destinationPath, json);
    }
}
```

Comment: What are `Match_` and `IP` and where are they defined?

Comment: IP is just another string i am adding to the row i am taking from the Excel.
Match_ is taken from where the linkQuery (if you see Match_ = IP + row[0]) it litteraly takes Match_ as is on text when it coverts to Json.

Comment: It seems like a rather odd thing to do with json. Json describes lists, but the index is implicit. Are you sure that a format like CSV would not be better for your use case?

Comment: its for my job, as i need to convert Excels to Jsons to make work more efficient rather than doing it manually.
so far everything is working, it converts everything i need and all the texts except that annoying Match that i need to add numbers after it somehow. 
so far its writing it off as.

The Correct text = its doing what i need it to write, i just cant post it sorry :P 
Match_ = "correct text" 
Match_ = "correct text" 

and i need it as

Match_1 = "correct text"
Match_2 = "correct text"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after it is assigned `query` is an `IEnumerable<>` of your anonymous type that will have 0 to many rows. Those rows are not actually evaluated yet. The important think to remember is that you are making an anonymous type, not an anonymous object, so all enumerations of your result must be of that type, you can't switch one by one.

There are many way to achieve what you want but possibly the most expedient is to include the iterator in your select enumerator, then return a [`JObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) something like this,

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

...

var query = rdr.Cast<DbDataRecord>().Select((row, i) => {
    var result = new JObject();
    result.Add( $"match_{i}", IP + row[0]);
    return result;
});
```

Then you won't have to do any error prone and costly string manipulation on your JSON, it will already be formatted correctly.

[Here is a full working example of this in action](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5ketHh),

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Linq;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var query = Enumerable
            .Range(1,5)
            .Select( (n, i) =>
               {
                   var result = new JObject();
                   result.Add($"match_{i}", n);
                   return result;
               });
        
        Console.WriteLine(
            JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
                query, 
                Formatting.Indented));
    }
}
```

[It is possible to do this with the more modern System.Text.Json but you'll have to embed the work in a writer.](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/try-the-new-system-text-json-apis/)

Comment: Hi, i am trying this one, but i have error on the "add" JsonObject does not contain a definition for 'add'

Comment: sorry i am still a little new to coding, now i got error about.

jsonvalue.pars unexpected character 'h'. at line 1, column 0.'

i believe its because of the String IP = "texticantshow"  (as it starts with h, and everytime i change it, it says a unexpeceted character so its something with it)

Comment: @odedgross I overhauled my answer

Comment: Thank you so much, i will try this!

Comment: @odedgross, if this worked or was helpful you might consider indicating so on the answer.

Comment: Hey @Jordell   i am sorry it was rude of me, it didnt work at the start so i didnt want to nag...  but after i changed 1 more thing in my code,  the code YOU gave me worked like a charm.
thank you so much! it helped.  and again sorry for delay

Answer (score 0):

Try regex.

```
    class Program
    {
        int i = 0;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string json = "match_   abc match_  def match_ hijmatch_";
            string pattern = "match_";

            Program p = new Program();
            MatchEvaluator myEvaluator = new MatchEvaluator(p.ReplaceCC);
            Regex r = new Regex(pattern);
            string output = r.Replace(json, myEvaluator);

        }
        public string ReplaceCC(Match m)
        // Replace each Regex cc match with the number of the occurrence.
        {
            i++;
            return m.Value + i.ToString();
        }
    }
```